# Renaming the model Directory in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I renamed the model dir from /home/abcd/andrew_model_jul25_tif/ which contained model and summary directories to /home/abcd/andrew_model_sep22/ which contained the same two folders. When I ran the python script it gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eval_on_full_image.py", line 127, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/abcd/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "eval_on_full_image.py", line 119, in main
    do_eval_on_whole(model_dir, file, file[a:], output_dir)
  File "eval_on_full_image.py", line 51, in do_eval_on_whole
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir))
  File "/home/abcd/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1602, in latest_checkpoint
    if file_io.get_matching_files(v2_path) or file_io.get_matching_files(
  File "/home/abcd/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 334, in get_matching_files
    compat.as_bytes(single_filename), status)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/home/abcd/virtualenvs/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/abcd/andrew_model_jul25_tif/model
```

When I changed the folder's name back to andrew_model_jul25 the script worked. Can changing the folder's name have such an effect?

I'm using the 1.1.0 version of tf, and running it on a GPU.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code and how you are changing your dir name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises here:

```
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_dir))
```

Try updating the name of your `model_dir` variable

Comment: thats just an arg that I type into the cmd line and the program takes in and looks there for the model.. I typed in the new directory and this was happening.